# One stored procedure calls another - however getting a table error

Tags: mysql

I am trying to call one stored procedure withing another - using an if statement.
I am getting an error so I believe that I have something out of sequence

```
CREATE PROCEDURE reportFreeCoolingTrackerCalls (
        IN fromDate varchar (50),
        IN toDate varchar (50),
        IN timeZone varchar (50))

    BEGIN
            DECLARE startDate varchar (50);
            DECLARE endDate varchar (50);
            DECLARE mylogID Int;

             SET startDate = FROM_UNIXTIME(fromDate/1000);
             SET endDate = FROM_UNIXTIME(toDate/1000);

     IF (l1.activityId = t2.activityId) 
      THEN CALL reportFreeCoolingTrackerError (
        fromDate,
        toDate,
        timeZone );
    ELSEIF  (l1.activityId != t2.activityId)
       THEN CALL reportFreeCoolingTracker (
        fromDate,
        toDate,
        timeZone );
            END IF;


  SELECT l1.activityId,t2.activityId
  FROM logs l 
      INNER JOIN groups g ON g.groupId = l.groupId
      LEFT JOIN groups g1 ON g.parentId = g1.groupId
      LEFT JOIN groups g2 ON g1.parentId = g2.groupId
      LEFT JOIN groups g3 ON g2.parentId = g3.groupId                
      INNER JOIN activities a ON l.logId = a.logId 
      INNER JOIN log1644 l1 ON a.activityId = l1.activityId 
      INNER JOIN log1644 t2 ON t2.recordId = l1.recordid + 1
      INNER JOIN items i ON l.logId = i.logId AND i.name LIKE '%KW%'
      INNER JOIN users u ON l1.userId = u.userId AND i.name LIKE '%KW%'
     WHERE i.itemID = "31985"  AND  l1.activityId = 1257
      AND l1.started
        BETWEEN startDate
            AND endDate 
     ORDER BY l1.recordId,l1.started;

    END //

DELIMITER ;
```

ERROR

Unknown table 'l1' in field list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table aliases (such as `INNER JOIN log1644 l1 ON...` are only visible in the statement (in your case a `SELECT`) that contains them.

You'll need to refer to the full table name outside of that select.

As for the logic.... you'll need to populate the values you need in the SP call by using a select, and populating them into variables. Alternatively, use a select subquery in the call itself, but that would be a maintenance headache!

Answer (score 2):

I think this code is causing the trouble for you:

```
IF (l1.activityId = t2.activityId)  --Here l1 and t2 are not known
  THEN CALL reportFreeCoolingTrackerError (
    fromDate,
    toDate,
    timeZone );
ELSEIF  (l1.activityId != t2.activityId) --Here l1 and t2 are not known
   THEN CALL reportFreeCoolingTracker (
    fromDate,
    toDate,
    timeZone );
        END IF;
```

as in this line l1 is not known. Similarly t2 is also not known